# jQuery - How to get attribute of an element when using the 'click' event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to get a click on an 'a' element. I have a list of those links where each one has a class which by him I'm capturing the click.

I would like to know which of the links has been clicked (I have an attribute 'setid' for each link) and also get the point where the mouse has been clicked.

How could this be accomplished?

example of the code:

```
<a href="#" class="newItem" setid="28">click me</a>

$('.newItem').click(function (e) {
    alert(e.attr('setid'));
});
```

EDIT:
OK, so to get the position I would use e.pageX

Comment: If you are going to add arbitrary attributes to your HTML, like "setid", you may want to consider adding the "data-" flag as this will pass validation.  Essentially  setid="28" isn't valid, but data-setid="28" is.

Comment: Michael - Thanks for the code :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To use jQuery methods you have to wrap **this** with a call to jQuery.

```
$('.newItem').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('setid'));
});
```

Comment: Hello, I'm having some problems with the .click(function(e)) { } when using IE9 for an anchor tag. Any idea how to get the attribute without using JQuery .click? example: function doClickFunction() { $(this).attr('class'); } doesn't work when you use plain JS and JQuery $(this)

Comment: Ask as new question please.

Answer (score 4):

refer to the code given below:

```
document.getElementById("element_id").addEventListener("click",function(e)
{
 console.log(e.srcElement.getAttribute("data-name"));
},false);
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. I was looking for a vanilla way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Like Skylar said in the comment to your question, you can use "data-" in front of your new attribute (which is HTML5 valid).

```
<a href="#" class="newItem" data-setid="28">click me</a>
```

Then in jQuery (v1.4.3+) you can get it like:

```
var setid = $(this).data("foo");
```

It's even a little nicer than attr() that other people have mentioned. See this for more examples - http://www.broken-links.com/2010/11/18/data-attributes-in-html-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You're on the correct path.

```
$(function(){

    $('.newItem').click(function () {
        alert( $(this).attr('setid') );
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right to get the attribute. The only thing missing is wrapping `this` (a DOM element) in the jQuery wrapper so you can use jQuery functions. `$(this).attr('setid')` should work.

To get the page coordinates, use the `pageX` and `pageY` properties of the event object. So:

```
$('.newItem').click(function (e) { // e is the event object
    alert($(this).attr('setid'));
    alert(e.pageX);
    alert(e.pageY);
});
```

See the documentation on the [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).